# How do I keep looping in a do-while loop as long as the default part of a switch triggers?

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while

What I am trying to accomplish: when the user types in anything other than 1 or 2, there will be a prompt saying `"I don't understand you"` and it would ask the user to choose 1 or 2 again without having to run the program each time.

Something like this:

```
do {
    String a = input.nextLine();
    num = Integer.parseInt(a);
    switch (num) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("hello");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("goodbye");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("I don't understand you");
    }
} while (num == default);
```

I know typing this will give me an error, so how do I compare it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Your loop would loop forever.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I'm certain there is a better way than approaching it with a dowhile loop

Comment: The logic of your speculative construct itself doesn't make sense here. You only have 3 cases, one for `1`, one for `2` and one for *everything else*. You don't need to validate.

Comment: what  i am trying to accomplish is when the user types in anything else but 1 or 2, there will be a prompt saying "i dont understand you" and would ask the user to choose 1 or 2 again without having to run the program each time. @andrewdleach

Comment: I edited your theoretical code to fit better with your intention - `num == 1 || num == 2 || num == default` would match everything, but, based on your comment, you only want to continue when `num` is "equal to" `default`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a potential infinite loop because the value for `num` which controls the stoping condition is never updated inside the loop.

Second, you could introduce a local variable to track when the user input was understood and exit the loop on that condition:

```
boolean understood;
do {
    understood = false;

    String a = input.nextLine();
    int num = Integer.parseInt(a);

    switch (num) {
        case 1:
               System.out.println("hello");
               understood = true;
               break;
         case 2:
               System.out.println("goodbye");
               understood = true;
               break;
         default:
               System.out.println("i dont understand u");
               break;
    }
} while (!understood);
```

Comment: thank you very much! this helped me a lot and i understand better now

Comment: It's not just a *potential* infinite loop - it *is* an infinite loop given that, if it were valid Java syntax, `while(num == 1 || num == 2 || num == default)` would literally match anything at all.

Comment: Or set `understood` to `true` in the beginning and `false` in `default` - that seems less error-prone and less typing than including that in every case.

Answer (score 0):

What you asked is technically a while(true) since everything which is not 1 or 2 is default. Also you should probably put your scanning bit in the loop.

If you try to check if value is different from 1 and 2 to ask again for a valid option:

```
do
{
    // stuff
}
while( num != 1 && num != 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "default" is a keyword you just can not compare it to anything. It's meaningless though, because in your condition you used all possible cases(case 1 and case 2), so your code will never end, printing either "hello" or "goodbye" forever.